# Using BeautifulSoup get "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Parser to get a list of best universities in China. I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'' error message:

> File "C:/Projects/Beijing Python/Week 2/Unit 06.py", line 22, in fillUnivList
>       for tr in soup.find('tbody').children:
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'

If I check mannually, "soup.find('tbody').children" statement is ok. What's wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
def getHTMLText(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
        r.raise_for_stasus()
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
        return r.text
    except:
        return ""


def fillUnivList(ulist, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for tr in soup.find('tbody').children:
        if isinstance(tr, bs4.element.Tag):
            tds = tr('td')
            ulist.append([tds[0].string, tds[1].string, tds[3].string])


def printUnivList(ulist, num):
    print("{:^10}\t{:^6}\t{:^10}".format('排名', '学校名称', '总分'))
    for i in range(num):
        u = ulist[i]
        print("{:^10}\t{:^6}\t{:^10}".format(u[0], u[1], u[2]))


def main():
    uinfo = []
    url = 'http://www.zuihaodaxue.cn/zuihaodaxuepaiming2016.html'
    html = getHTMLText(url)
    fillUnivList(uinfo, html)
    printUnivList(uinfo, 20)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `request` object doesn't have `raise_for_stasus()`. It is a typo - it's `raise_for_status()`. Also you can do with `status_code`.

Doing

```
def getHTMLText(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
        if r.status_code  == 200:
            r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
            return r.text
    except  Exception, e:
        print (e)
        return ""
```

And changing your `find` to `for tr in soup.find('tbody', class_="hidden_zhpm").children:`

Seems to work.

Comment: One more, what's is class_="hidden_zhpm? I can't find any information about it in google.

Comment: Personal choices. Either use raise for raising an error or check the type for the one you desire. You can find an html element by its class, that is what `class_` is for.